# REST Resource Naming & @PathVariable annotation

Tags: rest, spring-boot, response, restful-architecture, restful-url

I am reading a tutotral regarding the REST Resource Naming...

```
http://api.example.com/device-management/managed-devices/{id}/scripts/{id}:clone
```

This is an example of a best practice in the naming, but I don't know how to declare it using the `@PathVariable` annotation and distinguish one `{id}` from `{id}:clone`

```
public ResponseEntity<?> clone (
HttpServletRequest request, 
@PathVariable long id, ...) {
..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish the two IDs by the name of the variable or by the attribute `value` from `@PathVariable`, like:

```
@GetMapping("http://api.example.com/device-management/managed-devices/{idManagedDevice}/scripts/{idScript}"
public ResponseEntity<?> clone (HttpServletRequest request, 
    @PathVariable long idManagedDevice,
    @PathVariable long idScript,
) {
..
}
```

Or:

```
@GetMapping("http://api.example.com/device-management/managed-devices/{id}/scripts/{idScript}"
public ResponseEntity<?> clone (HttpServletRequest request, 
    @PathVariable(value="id") long idOfManagedDevice,
    @PathVariable(value="idScript") long idOfScript,
) {
..
}
```